# Can you void a condominium agreement of purchase and sale using the Status Certificate condition when nothing is obviously wrong in it?

Tags: contract-law, property

Here's what the contract says:

> This offer is conditional upon the Buyer obtaining an existing status Certificate from the seller at Seller's expense within Ten[10]banking days from acceptance of this offer and this offer is conditional upon the buyer finding the aforesaid certificate to his/her satisfaction, in his/her sole discretion, within Three[3] banking days after receiving same, otherwise this offer shall become null and void and the deposit shall be returned to the Buyer without interest or deduction. This condition is included for the benefit of the Buyer and may be waived at his sole option.

Upon Status Certificate was reviewed by my lawyer, he suggested to add a few other clauses to protect me (the buyer) from some unexpected circumstances. The seller would normally have no reason to reject them provided that everything is fine with the unit. If the seller does not agree those additional clauses, what leverages do I have? Can I threaten to void the contract using the above condition? Note that my lawyer didn't find anything that is absolutely unacceptable in the status Certificate. The only findings that I can be unsatisfied are subjective ones, such as pet policy, parking spot size, etc. I live in Ontario, Canada.

Comment: I'm not the one who VTC your question, but it is confusing: Why is the buyer required to obtain (rather than receive) a certificate from the seller to buyer's satisfaction? what does the certificate certify? The clause sounds absurd no matter who entered it. If the seller entered it, he can fulfill his obligation simply by issuing whatever certificate the buyer (you) wants. If you/buyer drafted it, why not require the certificate (and in the terms you want) *prior* to acceptance of the offer? Even better: Why not amend your clause so as to readily include all the terms you actually want?

Comment: Surely this is something for you to ask your lawyer about.  This site is not for getting legal advice on specific situations.